# Displaying sequential if's with Slim

Tags: html, slim-lang

I have the following paragraph that I'd like to display, depending on what customer information is available

```
p 
  ' Products and services are provided by #{link.company_name}
  - if link.support_email.present?
      div Email: #{mail_to link.support_email}
  - if link.support_phone.present?
      div Phone: #{link.support_phone}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use conditionals to properly display these items sequentially ..

The snippet I've shared above does **NOT** work .. the nesting is broken, so I get:

```
<p> ... </p>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

instead of:

```
<p>
  <div>..</div>
  <div>..</div>
</p>
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not a Slim issue. It's simply an HTML limitation.

According to the HTML spec, a `p` element `"cannot contain block-level elements"`.

You can read more about it in this section of the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1